# How to find ahref link inside a <li>

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
<div class="body>
   <ul class = "graph">
      <li>
            <a href = "Address one"> Text1
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
            <a href = "Address two"> Text2
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
            <a href = "Address three"> Text3
            </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am doing a web scraping project right now and I am having trouble extracting these ahref links above.

right now I have

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
content = soup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

I tried using the find_all('a') and get('href') functions but they dont seem to work in this situation.

Comment: The documentation is very [readable](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"I tried ... don't seem to work" is useless here.  We can't fix code you didn't post, for a problem you didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
for x in content.find_all('li'):
    href = x.find('a').get('href')
    print(href)
```